# which model is preferable for handling bugs?

Tags: agile

**Model 1:**

- Team 1: Dev Team for handling feature stories and bugs of same
  sprint/release
- Team 2: Maintenance Team for handling bugs of previous releases

Team members exchanged between Dev and Maintenance team every release so that morale of Maintenance team doesnot go down

- Pro : All features are delivered as per plan, Team is not disturbed
- Con : Team may have to work fix bugs on the features they have not
  worked on.May take more time to fix issue and originator of the issue
  will not get to know what mistake he has done and can do the same
  mistake again, code merging is required

Probably, this risk can be mitigated if in sprint retrospective or
release retrospective - dev and support team handshake occurs.
Require Knowledge transfer of application from dev team to
maintenance team in every release end

**Model 2:**

- Team : Same Team for handling features and bugs
- [StackExchangeLink](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/handling-bugs-in-the-scrum-process)

Decide , these many bugs team will fix every release - lets say 10 bugs
So team velocity is lets say 20 story point per sprint (excluding bugs which will be mentioned separately in status report)

- Pro : All fixes will be carried out by those who were responsible for
  that so they will realize their mistake
- Con : Not sure how much time each bug will take , sometimes it takes
  few hours and sometimes a day so its going to seriously hamper
  feature story plan

Please share your views.

Comment: This old post may help you: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/handling-bugs-in-the-scrum-process

Comment: @Zsolt, added your link in Model2 ...its not a comparison. But its a very good post that tells about Model2. It will definitely help.

Comment: "Not sure how much time each bug will take". - work on this. Measure velocity in the same way as with features.Rely on teh judegment of your team. You missed "Merging is expensive and awful" from your model 1 cons.

Comment: @NathanCooper, updated the cons of Model1

Comment: What does the dev team think?

Comment: @JeffLindsey, we are in proposal phase so dev team is to be formed yet

Comment: @DimpleSahani My advice would be to compile and summarize the recommendations and approaches you find, and then discuss it with the teams and ultimately let them decide. After a reasonable amount of time has passed to allow them to evaluate it, revisit it and keep/change it as needed.

Comment: @JeffLindsey , you are right ...we can start with Model2 and after discussion with team and client , if required , we can have Model1...Right now,we have to suggest some Model in proposal stage only but as you suggested , we will add this point and we will keep this option open

Comment: Operations and support are not projects. Are you sure this isn't just a capacity question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Model 2**

With Model one you may achieve *"All features are delivered as per plan, Team is not disturbed"* but the features are not actually complete because there are bugs still to be closed. This can lead to extremely dysfunctional behaviour where delivery of a feature is more important than whether it actually works, is secure and if the code is of decent quality.

Have each team responsible for maintaining their own work. Task them with completing work pulled into each sprint to the "definition of done". Where work was not properly completed in a previous sprint and takes effort to fix in a future sprint you are getting a more accurate impression of your actual velocity by 'losing' time fixing the issues later. The time lost later should really have been spent in the original sprint on that task rather than on starting another one.

Answer (score 1):

Some disadvantages of Model 1:

- By creating two teams you immediately introduce imbalance. Maybe one week there is a lot of project work to do, but the next week the focus needs to be on fixing production bugs. With the two teams concept you are likely to have one team overworked and one team under-worked.
- One of the big benefits of Scrum is to have a consistent team. This allows us to predict the capacity of the team. If you change the team members frequently it will be difficult to predict capacity.
- You can end up with a false impression of progress. The development team appears to be moving along quickly, but there is a backlog of production bugs building up. All appears well, but the reality is very different.
- It does not encourage pride in the quality of the development. If another team has to fix the production problems the development team is insulated from the mistakes they make.

Model 2 would be my preference. You rightly point out that predicting the time to fix bugs is difficult. That is one of the reasons teams often focus on prevention rather than fixing issues after they have happened. Examples of this approach include the use of TDD, continuous integration and automated regression testing. Spend time up-front promoting quality so that the rate of bugs is reduced and then forward progress becomes more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

### I recommend the same Team for handling features and bugs

> Team members exchanged between Dev and Maintenance team every release
>   so that morale of Maintenance team does not go down.

Try to keep the teams relatively stable, even if they switch from one project to another. This is because teams take time to gel together. Also, you can better predict velocity this way.

> excluding bugs which will be mentioned separately in status report

All work that the team will do in each sprint should be accounted for. So, estimate the bugs also with story points. See [Should Story Points Be Assigned to a Bug Fixing Story?](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/should-story-points-be-assigned-to-a-bug-fixing-story)

I get the impression (possibly incorrect) that your teams send too many bugs into production. If this is the case, you might want to review your current engineering practices and see how to tighten it up. You can ask the team in the next retrospective and implement the top suggestions on priority.

Answer (score 0):

We use a hybrid of both methods.

Due to our specific application we actually have new developers run bug support to help train and get use to the system.  As they grow they take on projects and handle bugs in the same fashion you discuss in Model 2.  Important customer support bugs get dedicated support from our new developers.  If the issue is big enough it goes into the features queue and the team works on it.  If the issue is an avoidable mistake or what we call a bug kickback (bug created by push or bug fix) then it's escalated to the member that creates it and we hold them to their schedule still.  We do see some push on the schedule but this usually is accepted by our business as important bugs that affect enough customers get their attention, developers are trained, and features don't take priority when the system is "failing."

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [stackexchange](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14971/which-strategies-i-can-use-to-handle-tickets-during-a-scrum-sprint) link

I could have added this in comments but I dont have enough points to do that